# Python: Minimum Numbers in List, Including Repeated Numbers

Tags: python, list

kinda new to python, and I'm having trouble coming up with a solution to this problem.

Suppose I have a list A and suppose I want to return a list B containing at least the three smallest values, including repeated values.  How would I write the logic for this?  I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to translate this thought into code.

Example:

```
    A = [1,2,3,4,4]
    b = [1,2,3]

    A = [1,2,3,3,4]
    B = [1,2,3,3]

    A = [1,1,2,2,3]
    B = [1,1,2,2]

    A = [1,1,2,3]
    B = [1,1,2]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `heapq` module:

```
import heapq

def nsmallestwithrepeats(A, n=3):
    b = heapq.nsmallest(n, A)
    try:
        b = set(b)
    except TypeError:
        pass
    return [a for a in A if a in b]

for A in [1,2,3,4,4], [1,2,3,3,4], [1,1,2,2,3], [1,1,2,3]:
    print(nsmallestwithrepeats(A))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 3]
[1, 1, 2, 2]
[1, 1, 2]
```

As @Mathieu Borderé points out instead of forming a set it is probably more efficient to simply compare to the largest element of b:

```
def nsmallestwithrepeats(A, n=3):
    b = heapq.nsmallest(n, A)
    return [a for a in A if a <= b[-1]]
```

Comment: does `nsmallest` return the result in sorted order? If so, you could take the last item returned from `nsmallest` as nthsmallest and return `[a for a in A if a <= nthsmallest]` instead of creating a `set`.

Comment: @MathieuBorderé Good point. It says in the docs "equivalent to sorted ... [:n]" so I suppose it does.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I ended up using heapq, and it does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

We can use a `set` to obtain distinct values, then keep the smallest 3. 
Then we keep only the values from A that are part of these 3.

```
def smallest_3_with_repeats(A):
    smallest_distinct = sorted(list(set(A)))[:3]
    return [x for x in sorted(A) if x in smallest_distinct] 

for A in [[1,2,3,4,4], [1,2,3,3,4], [1,1,2,2,3],
          [1,1,2,3],[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4] ] :
    print(A, "-->", smallest_3_with_repeats(A))

#[1, 2, 3, 4, 4] --> [1, 2, 3]
#[1, 2, 3, 3, 4] --> [1, 2, 3, 3]
#[1, 1, 2, 2, 3] --> [1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
#[1, 1, 2, 3] --> [1, 1, 2, 3]
#[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4] --> [1, 1, 1, 2, 3]
```

**Edit**: as Paul Pantzer noted, this is not exactly what the OP requested.
We want to have at least 3 values in the result, but not necessarily all of the 3 distinct smallest.

So, a complying version:

```
def smallest_3_with_repeats(A):
    smallest_distinct = sorted(list(set(A)))[:3]
    smallest = []
    for val in smallest_distinct:
        smallest.extend([x for x in A if x == val])
        if len(smallest) >= 3:
            break
    return smallest


for A in [[1,2,3,4,4], [1,2,3,3,4], [1,1,2,2,3],
          [1,1,2,3],[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4] ] :
    print(A, "-->", smallest_3_with_repeats(A))

# [1, 2, 3, 4, 4] --> [1, 2, 3]
# [1, 2, 3, 3, 4] --> [1, 2, 3, 3]
# [1, 1, 2, 2, 3] --> [1, 1, 2, 2]
# [1, 1, 2, 3] --> [1, 1, 2]
# [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4] --> [1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: That's not really what OP is asking for, is it? Cf. their examples.

Comment: Oh... Yes, you're right, I had really misread the question... I'll come back at it...

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally do it like this:

```
def get_mins(my_list, how_many):
    sorted_list = sorted(my_list)
    return [i for i in sorted_list if i != sorted_list[-1]][:how_many]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_mins([1, 2, 3, 4, 4], 3))
    print(get_mins([1, 2, 3, 3, 4], 4))
    print(get_mins([1, 1, 2, 2, 3], 4))
    print(get_mins([1, 1, 2, 3], 3))
    print(get_mins([1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4], 4))
```

The output will be:

> ```
> [1, 2, 3]
> [1, 2, 3, 3]
> [1, 1, 2, 2]
> [1, 1, 2]
> [1, 1, 1, 2]
> ```

Nothing fancy, no extra-modules needed.

The function takes two parameters:

- your list
- how many values you want in your new list

The function uses a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and adds to the new list all the values that are different from the maximum (in our case, the last element of the `sorted_list`).

Comment: `return a list B containing at least the three smallest values, including repeated values` .  get_mins([1, 1, 2, 2,2, 3, 4], 4) does not meet the requirements.

Comment: @mootmoot wut ? How come ? It returns the smallest 4 values, including the repeated ones. If you only need 3, turn the second argument from a `4` to a `3` :)

Comment: It is not just "limit to x number of values", but also must return the values if repetitive. e.g.  [1,2,3,3,3,3,4,4] -> [1,2,3,3,3,3]  ;   [1,2,2,2,2,4] -> [1,2,2,2,2]

Answer (score 0):

not much experienced with python...but this seems to be working..
If A[] is not sorted you can use sorted(A) as well

```
A = [1,1,2,2,2,3]
B = []
count = 0
i = 0
while count<3 or A[i] == A[i-1]:
    B.append(A[i])
    i = i+1
    count = count + 1
print B
```